# Time validation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, date, time

We have a generic search text box and user can search any thing. I need to validate DateTime and particularly time part and user can enter any thing
**docdate eq 1/1/2000 33:28:00**
**docdate eq 1/1/2000 13:28am**
In the above queries I need to validate date part knowing the column docdate is valid date.
What could be best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) is what you're looking for.

It will attempt to parse a date (returning true if valid, false if not), and provide a System.DateTime value if successful.
One of the overloads lets you specify the specific formats you'd like to support.

The TryParse method is preferable to string parsing / regular expressions because it:

- Handles the various date / time rules (number of days per month, leap years, etc) and formats for multiple cultures
- Supports all date / time values that can be represented by a System.DateTime object
- Provides a System.DateTime object for valid dates, which is likely needed elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime.TryParse like this to convert from military time.

```
DateTime parsedDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact("1/1/2000 3:28:00", "M/d/yyyy H:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Play around with the format string (the 2nd parameter) to test various possible formats (for example: with and without am/pm, with and without milliseconds...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularValidation. You can find the appropriate expression from [here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=5&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

```
(?n:^(?=\d)((?<day>31(?!(.0?[2469]|11))|30(?!.0?2)|29(?(.0?2)(?=.{3,4}(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))|0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?<sep>[/.-])(?<month>0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?<year>(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(?<time>((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(?i:\ [AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$)
```